# use RecyclerView like vertical viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

is this possible to use recyclerview like verticalpager .
what I want is when a user scrolls always the first item offset from the top be zero. like when you scroll in viewpager. is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can use a simple LinearLayoutManager:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
```

and for `RecyclerView.Adapter` View item use `layout_height="match_parent"` to get View on full width of screen.

or just use this lib: [RecyclerViewPager](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager)

---

Updated:

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(int newState) {
        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // special handler to avoid displaying half elements
            scrollToNext();
        }
        animate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
        animate();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi victore thanks for your attention, but like i said i want a verrtical srolling and i use match_parent to fill all view but my problem is when users scroll, i want my items always be top "normally screen can be half from one item and half from another wich i dont want",and i cannot use viewpager for some resaons.thanks again.

Comment: @max ok, i understood. in this case i recommend you to implement custom `LayoutManager`. Useful article http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/

Comment: @max,Did You find Solution for this problem?

Answer (score 52):

Since API level 25 there's a `PagerSnapHelper` for that:

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457668/3252261).

Comment: Now this class is the part of RecyclerView compat library. You can use it on devices below api 25